# Unity3d: streaming AudioClip loaded with WWW from disk

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine, audio-streaming

I load the ogg-files from the disk with the WWW.

```
    var www = new WWW (@ "file://C:/myfile.ogg");
    yield return www;
    // Next line hangs
    var clip = www. audioClip;
```

As I see Unity hangs for 1000 ms when loading ogg file into memory. I've tried do this operation in an other thread but Unity does not allow it.

Why don't I preload all the music? Because when downloading these files, 10-15 (3-5 MB) UnityEngine takes 1.5 GB of RAM.

In audio import inspector I can configure the StreamFromDisk option. Then, the audio will be streamed directly from the disk and will not take up memory.

How can I stream files like in the inspector that I read from the disk with WWW?

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you make your imported AudioClip into an assetbundle, and load it as such - the stream-from-disk option will be preserved.
I have not tested this, but i would suspect it to work.